# How to do ajax call inside the loop using javascript

Tags: php, html, mysql

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Trk.png)   I am fetching all the value from **location table** and based on the particular **location**(eg. delhi) I want to show all the **area**(different area of delhi)of particular location using **ajax call** inside the loop.
This is **index.php** page

```
//ajax call for location
function cityArea(area) {
    if (city == " ") {
        document.getElementById("mapp").innerHTML = " ";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("mapp").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "city_area.php?q=" + area, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}



<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <form name="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <?php   
                   $sql="select * from location order by id desc";                      
                   $q=$conn->query($sql);
                   if($q->num_rows>0)
                   {
                       while($r1=$q->fetch_assoc())
                       {                                
                           echo '                           
                            <div class="col-sm-12">                      
                             <div class="col-sm-12">
                                  <p>city:</p>
                                    <p onload="cityArea('.$r1['city'].')">'.$r1['city'].'</p>
                                    <div id="mapp"></div>
                                </div>
                                 </div>                 
                             ';
                       }
                   }
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This page is saved as **city_area.php**. Here Am trying to do ajax call through this page. But am not getting the value. Where am wrong pls correct me

```
<div id="mapp" name=" " class="form-control">
    <?php
        $city=$_GET['q'];
        $qry11 = "select area from location where `city`='$city'";
        $q11=$conn->query($qry11);
        if($q11->num_rows >0)
        {
           while($r11=$q11->fetch_assoc())
            {
             echo "
                 <label value='".$r11['area']."'>".$r11['area']."</label>
             ";  
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

**This is my database table**

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `location` (`id`, `city`, `area`) VALUES
(1, 'delhi', 'mayur bihar'),
(2, 'delhi', 'sarita bihar');
```

Comment: What do you see in developers console? `id` btw __must__ be unique on the page.

Comment: you have two closing `</head>` tags - invalid markup

Comment: I removed the extra tag...pls guide me where am doing wrong

Comment: `<p onload="cityArea.....` - the `onload` event should be on the document. The ajax call, if successful, would then add another div with duplicate id `mapp` which also is invalid

Comment: the ajax function has an argument `area` but you then check if `city==''`

Comment: am not getting properly...can u mention the code

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function had an unknown variable `city` used in the logic test - I presume that was meant to be `area`

```
function cityArea( area ) {
    var mapp=document.getElementById("mapp");
    if ( area == " " ) {
        mapp.innerHTML = " ";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                mapp.innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "city_area.php?q=" + area, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

There is no `onload` event for html elements - either assign to the body or as another type of event handler for the element - in this case I assumed this to be a `click` event to the paragraph. The call within to `cityArea` appears to have a mismatch of quotes - presumably the parameter being passed in is a string so it needs to be quoted.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <form name="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <?php

                   $sql="select * from location order by id desc";                      
                   $q=$conn->query($sql);

                    if( $q->num_rows>0 ){
                        while($r1=$q->fetch_assoc()){

                            echo '                           
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <p>city:</p><!-- changed quotes - escaped single quotes ( not tested ) -->
                                    <p onclick="cityArea( \''.$r1['city'].'\' )">'.$r1['city'].'</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                       }
                    }

                ?>
                <div id="mapp"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ajax call was attempting to return a div with an ID that already exists in the DOM so would render that invalid and would make targeting of elements useless due to the ambiguity of IDs.

```
<?php

    $city=!empty( $_GET['q'] ) ? $_GET['q'] : false;
    if( $city ){

        $qry11 = "select area from location where `city`='$city'";
        $q11=$conn->query( $qry11 );

        if( $q11 && $q11->num_rows > 0 ) {
           while( $r11=$q11->fetch_assoc() ){
             echo "<label value='".$r11['area']."'>".$r11['area']."</label>";  
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: am getting the same output as previous.....its showing only **city**. area(ajax call) is not fetching

Comment: is the ajax request getting triggered when you click on the paragraph?

Comment: am adding screenshot . ajax is getting triggered(**when am clicking on the delhi am getting the error**)

Comment: there was an error with my adjusted ajax function - simple mistake but corrected above

Comment: you need quotes around the passed in parameter

Comment: if you notice `<p onclick="cityArea( \''.$r1['city'].'\' )">` there are escaped single quotes in there

Comment: I seen it but still getting error..am adding snapshot once more ...am near to my answer ..I value your time but still pls spend little more time ...

Comment: see previous comment regarding error in the code i posted.. the ajax function has been modified above

Comment: I got the output...Thank you so much for giving your valuable time.....is there any other function  from which I can directly show the city with corresponding area without onclick of city?

Comment: in the loop you could push function requests into an array and execute after the loop. You could just add the content directly with PHP if there is no user interaction required and avoid all ajax routines. Hard to answer - many options but without knowing the full intent or seeing the full code it's hard to be precise

Comment: Glad that you are getting there with solving it though